# How to make a parameter to char C++

Tags: c++, char

I have a split-method which takes 2 parameters in, a char and a string:

```
split(char sk, string st)
```

But when I'm calling the method like below, I get this error-message:

> > expected primary-expression before ':' token

```
g.split(:, string);
```

Is it any way I can make call to understand that : is a char?

Comment: The question seems so trivial, that I'd suggest you start by reading a textbook on C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes

```
g.split(':', string);
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried "everything", but totally forgot the single quotes =)

Answer (score 3):

Use `g.split(':', string);`.

Single quotes do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes:

```
g.split(':', string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call like below in a valid way:

```
g.split(':', "string"); // can not pass string also simply (type is not expected)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes, `g.split(':', string);`